# Number in post meta not working for orderby

Tags: wordpress

ahoy-hoy

I am trying to use post meta to order a list of events. The meta key is _event_date and the meta value is stored 'yymmdd'. What I want is simple: I want the events, which are custom posts called 'events', to start at the event closest to the current date. But it ain't working.

Here's my code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => '_event_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

endwhile; endif;
```

So, is there anything that stands out as wrong with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may interest you, from WordPress Codex:

**Order & Orderby Parameters**

> *'**meta_value**'*
>
> Note that a 'meta_key=keyname' must also be present in    the query.
>   Note also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is    fine for
>   strings (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers    (e.g. 1, 3,
>   34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you    might
>   naturally expect). Use 'meta_value_num' instead for numeric    values.
>   You may also specify 'meta_type' if you want to cast the meta    value
>   as a specific type. Possible values are 'NUMERIC', 'BINARY',
>   'CHAR', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME', 'UNSIGNED',
>   same as in '$meta_query'. When using 'meta_type' you can also use
>   meta_value_* accordingly. For example, when using DATETIME as
>   'meta_type' you can use 'meta_value_datetime' to define order
>   structure.

So your query args should be:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => '_event_date',
    'meta_type' => 'DATE',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_date', 
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey iEmanuele. Thanks for referencing the codex and then writing the array. That helped a lot.

Comment: @producto, pls, mark as valid answer if your problem get solved, thanks