# Wordpress incorrect query ordering by meta key numeric

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm trying to order a custom taxonomy by a custom meta key. That meta key is the number of edition. Weekly, my client adds a new edition (the term of the "edition" taxonomy), and this number increases. At the moment, it is at 124.

So, I'm trying to order the admin list by this numeric meta key, this way:

```php
add_filter("get_terms_args", "mytheme_get_terms_args", 10, 2);

static function mytheme_get_terms_args($args, $taxonomies)
{
    if(is_admin() && in_array("edition", $taxonomies)){
        $args['order'] = "ASC";
        $args['orderby'] = "meta_value";
        $args['meta_key'] = "_edition";
        $args['meta_type'] = "DECIMAL";
    }
    
    return $args;
}
```

The expected result is all editions ordered as follows:

1, 2, 3, [...], 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, [...] 19, 20...

But, I'm getting this ordering instead:

1, 2, 3, [...], 9, 10, **100, 101, 102 , [...] 109, 11, 110, 111, 112, [...], 118, 119, 12, 120, 121, 122, 123**, 13, 14, 15...

After the 10, instead following to 11, this crazy ordering goes to 100, 101, 102.

How can I order this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Why use  $args['meta_type'] = "DECIMAL"; when you are using integers? This sorting issue is discussed in [Number in post meta not working for orderby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090575/number-in-post-meta-not-working-for-orderby)

Comment: Currently, the sorting is done _alphanumerically_, character by character, from left to right. You need to use `$args['orderby'] = "meta_value_num";`

Comment: @TimBrownlaw already tried with $args['meta_type'] = "NUMERIC", and without specifyinf the meta_type. Same result in both.

Comment: @CBroe already tried with $args['orderby'] = "meta_value_num" with and without meta_type, tried both with DECIMAL and NUMERIC. and the result is the same all times.

Comment: Are you sure you are changing the code in the right spot? If you have tried all of the above with no changes... I'd say somethings not quite right...

Comment: If you feed the same arguments (plus the taxonomy name) to `get_terms`, then you should be able to verify whether this sorts correctly, and the used filter or something else is to blame instead.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I think it's in the right place, since when I change any arguments (like 'order' to "ASC" or "DESC, or 'orderby' to "name" or "term_id"), it works. The problem is I can't order my terms by the "_edition" meta key, which is numeric. Looks like Wordpress is treating it as string instead number, and doesn't order correcly due to char-by-char ordering (10 to 100 instead to 11).